# Awarding bounty should be more clear

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bounties

On stackoverflow, I put +50 bounty on a question. Sure enough, a kind soul came and answered my question, so dutifully I clicked the check box for their answer and considered it done with. However, today I got a notification that my bounty was going to expire in 3 days - apparently you have to click the blue +50 icon to award bounty as well.

My suggestion: I had thought that accepting an answer awarded the bounty. I think that it would be better to make this actually the case, or at least surface a dialog box asking the user whether they also want to award the bounty for the question.

Comment: Awarding the bounty through accepting *used* to be how the system worked, so we're not going back to that. However, I do think a case can be made to prompt the user to manually award the bounty if there is one active on the question (and the same user started it).